# What are the default iperf3 values?

Tags: iperf3

From:

https://www.mankier.com/1/iperf3#--length

I can only see:

> length of buffer to read or write.  For TCP tests, the default value
>   is 128KB.

**Q:** But what sizes do iperf use to test the connection between the nodes? Cannot find any DOC about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `iperf3` client and/or server with these options `--json --logfile output.json --forceflush`. That file may confirm the default values you are using.

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

`iperf3` message/packet length is specified using the `-l` parameter.  You can view the size used using the `-V` (verbose) parameter.  `iperf3` will print a message starting with "*Starting Test: ...*" that shows the "*byte blocks*" size of the packets.